# MonoTouchBindings for RedLaser3.3.0

Tags: xamarin.ios

are there any MonoTouch Bindings for the RedLaserSdk 3.3. I only found bindings for the 2.4 Version. Here are the latest bindings that i´ve found: https://github.com/chrisbranson/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/RedLaser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try out using the 2.4 bindings.  If RedLaser made any changes it shouldn't be too hard to add them yourself.

Just make sure to submit a pull request if you fix anything for 3.3.